# ¿Cómo cambiar leyenda de mapa de la función qtm de la librería tmap - R-?

Tags: r, rstudio, mapa

Buenas deseo cambiar las etiquetas de la leyenda del siguiente mapa, para esto uso los paquetes `tmap` y `rgdal`:

Para esto tengo el siguiente vector, el cual se usa para realizar el mapa.

```
library(tmap)
library(rgdal)
dep1<-c(2.86,2.11,4.37,2.02,4.42,3.84,2.88,8.48,5.36,3.98,1.14,7.27,1.91,2.09,21.35,9.69,1.01,0.53,2.55,4.20,3.32,2.44,0.37,0.42,1.41)
```

Para el mapa uso un archivo shapefile.

```
mapa<-readOGR("DEPARTAMENTOS.shp")  # Este archivo se puede descargar desde el siguiente enlace: https://cutt.ly/MtGx7be
```

Luego uso los siguientes códigos para graficar.

```
mapa$freq<-dep1
mapa$freq_p<-paste(mapa$freq,"%")

mapa$nombre_valor<-paste(mapa$DEPARTAMEN,"\n", mapa$freq_p)

qtm(shp = mapa, fill = c("freq"),
            col = "Median_income", palette = "BuGn", scale = 0.7, fill.title="Porcentajes", title.font=1,
            fill.style="fixed", title.fontface=2,
            fill.breaks=round(c(seq(0, 12, length.out=7),Inf)),0)+
  tm_text("nombre_valor", size = 0.7)+
  tm_layout(legend.format = list(text.separator = "-"),frame = F, asp=NA)+
  tm_legend(legend.position = c("left", "bottom"))
```

A lo cual tengo el siguiente resultado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la parte izquierda está la leyenda, pero deseo cambiarlo para que aparezca cada número con el símbolo de porcentajes.

¿Que argumento tengo que usar? ¿O es posible hacerlo con otra librería?

**Muchas gracias de antemano**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes probar a modificarlo con:

```
legend.format=list(fun=function(x) paste0(formatC(x, digits=0, format="f"), " %"))
```

Obtenido de https://stackoverflow.com/a/45336985/5675636

Comment: Muchas gracias, se soluciona la falta de los porcentajes.. Sabe como puedo cambiar el `more` del final por `más`, sino sería pedir mucho.

Comment: @ARSENALCOYG Se supone que igual que existe la propiedad text.separator, existe text.or.more, prueba a ver si puedes cambiarlo accediendo a esa propiedad en el list.

Comment: Muchísimas Gracias. Gran aporte. Excelente,

Comment: Para eso estamos ;)